# Bootstrap - direct link to modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have an url like this:

`www.url.com/#imprint`
(or similar) to link directly to the page with the opened modal window?

is this possible? Any hints?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible. But it depends on why and how you want to use link.

Comment: I just got a single prepage for some weeks and I need to link directly to my imprint from other services. But my Imprint is in a modal window on the prepage. That's why ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this.

```
if (window.location.hash == "#imprint") {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for future visitors/readers, I have created a very simple function to open a modal *dynamically* without the need to know the exact ID that you're looking for. It just falls through if no hash is located.

```
/**
 * Function to open a bootstrap modal based on ID
 * @param int
 */
function directLinkModal(hash) {
  $(hash).modal('show');
}

/**
 * Call the function on window load
 * @param hash of the window
 */
directLinkModal(window.location.hash);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Just check URL:

```
function popModal() {
      // code to pop up modal dialog
    }

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash.substring(1) == 'modal1') {
      popModal();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After losing couple of hours I came up with this one. A solution for opening different modals at **page-2** based on the link that is clicked at **page-1**. The HTML code is based on Bootstrap official Modal examples.

**HTML | page-1.html**

```
<body>    
  <a href="http://yourwebsi.te/page-2.html?showmodal=1">
  <a href="http://yourwebsi.te/page-2.html?showmodal=2">
</body>
```

**JS | ShowModal.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if (url.indexOf('?showmodal=1') != -1) {
    $("#modal-1").modal('show');
  }
  if (url.indexOf('?showmodal=2') != -1) {
    $("#modal-2").modal('show');
  }
});
```

**HTML | page-2.html**

```
<body>    
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">Your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">Your content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="ShowModal.js"></script>
</body>
```